# mirror <details> and checkbox state across iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iFrame that loads its parent page within itself.  So, two copies of the same page; one in an iFrame, one not.

I'm trying to mirror the state of `<input type="checkbox">` `checked/unchecked` and `<details>` `open/closed` between the main page and the iFrame.

I have solved each partway (see `// comments` for the problems), firing on `click` events:

**For the checkboxes, I have**

```
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (let box of boxes)) {
    myIFrame.getElementById(box.id).checked = box.checked; // works
    if (inIFrame) {parent.getElementById(box.id).checked = document.getElementById(box.id).checked; // doesn't work
}
```

(the condition `inIFrame` above is just shorthand for a test checking whether the page is loaded in an iFrame)

**And for the `<details>`**

```
let detailEls = document.querySelectorAll('details');

for (let i = 0; i < detailEls.length; i++) {
  myIFrame.querySelectorAll('details')[i].open = querySelectorAll('details')[i].open; // works, but 1-click behind
  }
```

But strangely, this lags one click behind.  So if I click, click, click to open details A,B,C on the main page, only A,B will open in the iFrame -- and the next click, C will open.

In case it wasn't clear, here's the summary of my questions:

1. Why does the `<details>` state lag? It seems like the same strategy as for checkboxes, but the result is different.
2. Why does the checked state only mirror from the main page to the iFrame, but not vice versa?

Thanks!

Comment: `if (inIFrame) {parent.getElementById(box.id).checked = getElementById(box.id).checked;` In the right side of this statement, `getElementById` of what ?

Comment: And what about `PostMessage()`- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  (1) `box.id` is the element id taken from the loop, (2) thanks for the PostMessage tip, I'll look into that

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] of your code? Currently your code will not compile as you're not prefixing the `document` methods with `document` (e.g. `document.querySelector` instead of `querySelector`).

Comment: @Edric Sure, fixed.

Comment: `Why does the checked state only mirror from the main page to the iFrame, but not vice versa` this happens because you LITERALLY update the *iframe* `checked` with the *window* `checked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reproduction that demonstrates the behavior you want, generally following your patterns:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-mirror-iframe?file=lib/script.js

It's hard to tell without your full code, but here are some things to consider:

1. If you're using the `click` event on the details, that's probably giving you the "lagging" behavior. It turns out that for details, the `click` event comes *before* its `open` property is updated. The one you just clicked is always read in the wrong state when your synchronizer runs.

   - Use the `toggle` event instead, this fires *after* the `open` property is updated.
2. Assuming its not a typo in the first code block, `parent` is a reference to the parent *window*, not its *document*.

   - Use `parent.document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: Interesting! -- I wasn't aware of toggle vs open.  I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the logic that you use will not be able to `mirror vice-versa` as you would like it to, so I will make it on `click` bases **ON BOTH WINDOW AND IFRAME**

Here's my [repl](https://replit.com/@PaulTaylor2/iframe-mirror) and here's a [link(please open this in new tab)](https://iframe-mirror.paultaylor2.repl.co/)

Here's the concept:

- I make arrays of the elements I want `mirrored` on both `iframe` **AND** `window`. These arrays are made in the same *way* so that the `keys/indexes` each relate to their equivalent in the separate window(*`window.boxes[0]` is the first box in **window** and `childWindow.boxes[0]` is the first box in **iframe***)
- Now the most important part is the `async` part you would see in the `addEventListener` blocks. you would see me `await`ing a promise of a `timeout` that lasts *`0 ms`* but how asynchronous functions like that work is that it would wait until it isn't blocking anything and **THEN RUN**. That's why it ignores that lag effect the `detail` bars give

**window.html**

```
<html><h2>WINDOW</h2>
<iframe id="iframe" width="500" height="300" src="/"></iframe>

<details>.</details>
<details>..</details>
<details>...</details>
<details>....</details>
<details>.....</details>
<input type="checkbox">Hm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmmm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmmmm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmmmmm</input>

<script>(async()=>{
window.iframe=document.getElementById('iframe') //iframe
window.childWindow=iframe.contentWindow //window to iframe
window.waitFinish=async function(){ //needful waiting
  await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,0))
}

window.boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')] //checkboxes
window.details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')] //details

//wait for iframe to finish loading(if you're doing this manually by the time you begin it'd be finished loading so no worries)
await new Promise(r=>{
  let s=setInterval(()=>{
    if(typeof childWindow.details=="object"){
      clearInterval(s); return r(1)
    }
  },0)
})

//window to iframe
boxes.forEach((box,index)=>{
  box.addEventListener("click",async(ev)=>{
    await waitFinish()
    childWindow.boxes[index].checked=box.checked
  })
})
details.forEach((detail,index)=>{
  detail.addEventListener("click",async(ev)=>{
    await waitFinish()
    childWindow.details[index].open=detail.open
  })
})

//iframe to window
childWindow.boxes.forEach((box,index)=>{
  box.addEventListener("click",async(ev)=>{
    await waitFinish()
    window.boxes[index].checked=box.checked
  })
})
childWindow.details.forEach((detail,index)=>{
  detail.addEventListener("click",async(ev)=>{
    await waitFinish()
    window.details[index].open=detail.open
  })
})
})()</script>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<html><h2>IFRAME</h2>
<i><a target="_blank" href="https://iframe-mirror.paultaylor2.repl.co">Full Page</a></i>

<details>.</details>
<details>..</details>
<details>...</details>
<details>....</details>
<details>.....</details>
<input type="checkbox">Hm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmmm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmmmm</input>
<input type="checkbox">Hmmmmm</input>

<script>
window.boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')] //checkboxes
window.details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')] //details
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks -- upvoted -- that's a good suggestion about the 0ms async set timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You made a tiny mistake.
Your code was:

```
for (let box of querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    myIFrame.getElementById(box.id).checked = box.checked; // works
    if (inIFrame) {parent.getElementById(box.id).checked = getElementById(box.id).checked; // doesn't work
}
```

when it needs to be

```
for (let box of querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    myIFrame.getElementById(box.id).checked = box.checked; // works
    if (inIFrame) {parent.getElementById(box.id).checked = document.getElementById(box.id).checked; // works now that it's fixed
}
```

You forgot the `document` object as the parent.

Comment: Good catch, unfortunately it was just a typo here!

Comment: Huh, @ultraGentle?

Comment: Didn't reflect the original code.  Just a typo on SO.